# boolean modifiers working in viewport but not in renders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I think this is a simple fix with a setting somewhere that I have missed but I cannot for the life of me figure out why the boolean modifiers are not working properly in my renders.

Here is the viewport (please excuse the lack of textures)

[image]

And here is the render You can see that the boolean for the window isn't working. (The render is low sample with denoising and the light artefact is a reflection off the shower screen.)

[image]

I have double checked that the modifiers are ticked for the render and viewports, and have checked modifier and boolean object settings but cannot figure it out.

Here is the .blend file if you would like it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ik3yul655e23nqa/Chris%20House%201.blend?dl=0

Thanks in advance for your help.

Dan

Comment: Hello, maybe sipmlify your file, only keep one wall and one boolean so that we can quickly test your problem?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for you reply. I found the issue while simplifying the file, and have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ergh, so dumb. I found the issue while simplifying the file as suggested. It was a solidify modifier on the boolean object that was turned off in viewport but on in render. The issue arose because I created the bool object based on the window and didn't delete the modifier.